# What program can be used to insert/modify/delete rows of MS SQL Compact?

Tags: ms-sql

MS SQL Server Management Studio 2010 seems not support compact databases (add/remove records).

Is there any utility? Free one would be nice.

Comment: Do you mean something to graphically view and edit tables? Per my answer, SQL Server Management Studio does support adding and removing rows in SQL CE tables through the use of T-SQL Queries. Maybe modify your question if this was your intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like SQL Server Management Studio [does, indeed, support SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171805(v=SQL.105).aspx). However, depending on where you're actually hosting the instance from, [the best tool might be something different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171757.aspx).

If you're looking for a *graphical* tool (to view the tables, instead of using T-SQL queries), I found [this list of SQL Server Compact tools](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html). [CEQuery](http://cequery.codeplex.com/) looks particularly promising, and it's on CodePlex, so it's completely free.

Comment: I tried CEQuery but it crashes. SQL Server Management Studio doesn't support Edit Top 200 Rows either. I don't need to design DB tables, I need to insert/delete records in a grid interface.

Comment: I use SDF Viewer.

Comment: I didn't try any of them out; I don't use SQL CE because of a different set of limitations (no server-generated keys). Glad you found something that worked. The list I linked has a lot of similar ones listed, so if you continue to have problems you still have more options.